# How to add a keyword to many entries simultaneously in JabRef?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I want to add a keyword to many entries simultaneously in JabRef. How can I do this? Selecting the entries and writing the keyword in the Keywords textbox of JabRef only adds the keyword to the first selected entry.

I'll also accept a method that modifies directly the .bib file, maybe through some terminal command. However the disadvantage with that is that the terminal command cannot know which entries I have selected in JabRef, so that's not very user-friendly. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: You could use `sed` or `gawk` to modify the `.bib` file. I don't use JabRef so I've no idea about that.

Comment: I don't think that [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) has this capability. I suggest going to JabRef's feature request page

Answer (score 2):

Select the entries of interest and choose Search > Set/clear/rename fields:

[image]

Now change the `Keyword` field for all "Selected entries":

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I want (+1), but it doesn't solve my problem completely. Is there a way to *add* a new keyword to the selected entries, without deleting the old keywords those entries had?

Comment: @becko: Try unchecking the "Overwrite existing field values" option.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work. If the field is empty, it adds the keyword, but if the entry has some keywords already, it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

First select (highlight) all the entries you want the multiple keywords added
|JabRef2.10|>`Edit`>`Manage Keywords`

[image]

After typing in your comma delimited list press `Add` `OK`. All done :-)

[image]

It only adds the extra keywords you have added to all entries (not the complete list).

The only issue I have found (I don't know how it works and don't use it) is that if the keyword exists it is duplicated in those entries, as shown below.
[image]

Comment: It is possible. The trick is to select (unlike the example above shows) "Display Keywords appear in ALL entries" and then add the keywords one wants to add in the list. Hit add, which shows them in the big field and then OK, which enters them. If the keyword is already present, it will be duplicated...