# Add keyword via command line

Tags: command-line

I'm looking for a way to add a keyword to all the entries contained in a bibtex file. I came across this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261670/how-to-add-a-keyword-to-many-entries-simultaneously-in-jabref/261710) but no  example on how to do it through awk or sed is given.

Thanks